# Add Items dynamically in ListView without affecting other already added items in Android

Tags: android, listview, spinner

How to add Items dynamically in `ListView` such a way that it does not affect already added Items. 
I am using custom `ListView` which contains `TextView`, `Spinner` and `EditText`. I want that if user has entered some text in `EditText` and then if he/she adds another items then already added/changed values does not affect anyway. After that, I also want values of all 3 controls on `ButtonClick`
Please help me for this.

Answer (score 1):

Create adding method whitch will loop your listview adapter's items for the same and if contains this value then call `return` in add method or some other action, if not contains then add new item to your adapter and call for it `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update `ListView` in yuor `Activity` or `Fragment`.

```
void addMethodExample(String someValue) {
      for (String item : arrayInYourAdapter) 
          if (item.equals(someValue)
              return;
      arrayInYourAdapter.add(someValue);
      arrayInYourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

It's example of adding `String` value to the ListView. By this logic write adding method of item in your adapter's items array.

Comment: Can u give any example ?

Comment: @CSAT, try this one. If I understand U right then this example will help U.